# Should I install exterior door of mudroom before or after tiling?

Tags: doors, tiling, finish

I have a doorway leading from my newly added mudroom to the new garage. The doorway currently does not have a door in place yet. I have the door already (it is in the old doorway from the kitchen to the garage and still needs to be moved) and it has an aluminum threshold that is flush with the door.

I want to tile the mudroom floor, but not sure if I should wait until I have the exterior door separating the garage from the mudroom installed.

I fear that if I install the jamb and threshold after the tile work is done, the gap between the threshold and tile will be too large to grout. If I install the door first, I can take some steps to custom fit the tile against the threshold.

The door already has a threshold in place, which is the kind that sits flush with the face of the door (e.g. it doesn't overhang the edge of the flooring).

How is this situation typically handled?

Comment: Personally, door first, then floor, then trim.

Comment: That's the route I went. Thanks @stevieb